# ¿porque al usar el nextInt() automaticamente salta de linea en Java?

Tags: java

una pequeña duda en este código:

```
System.out.print("Digite el primer entero:");
  x = entrada.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Digite el segundo entero:");
  y = entrada.nextInt();
```

al ejecutar sale:

```
Digite el primer entero:4
Digite el segundo entero:6
```

mi pregunta es: ¿no debería salir así?:

```
Digite el primer entero:4Digite el segundo entero:6
```

ya que estoy utilizando System.out.print() y en ningún momento le estoy indicando al programa que debe saltar de linea ¿como haría para que siga escribiendo en la misma linea?

Comment: No sera que para leer de la consola el emplea el salto de linea, cómo le das a conocer que ya entrastes un numero cuando escribes en la consola???

Comment: con enter ¿osea que toma el enter como si fuera un salto de linea?

Comment: @Falricas Claro.... Scanner queda a la espera que ingreses la entrada y luego para tomarla debes presionar enter (que te lleva a la siguiente línea)

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que cuando pulsas enter se introducen los tokens de salto de linea lo que le indica al objeto scanner que ya se termino la entrada, en cambio si despues de que se lee el primer valor lo introduces asi

24 32

con el espacio, no te dejara leer el segundo por que en el buffer aun exiten valores y los leera automaticamente y cuando le das enter le indicas que se esta finalizando la entrada de valores.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto el nextInt() hace un salto de linea, ya que de esta manera se evitan confusiones. Aparte, si sacas el segundo print por ejemplo, parecería que estas ingresando distintos dígitos para un mismo campo.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. si supongo que es algo en como esta programado el método nextInt() pueda ser que guarde como parte de la cadena el enter que uno pulsa para indicarle al programa que ya esta la cadena pero para saberlo a exactamente habría que ver el código fuente del método.